# Simple debugging pls

Tags: python, debugging

I'm a sixth-grade student who's having trouble with some coding here.
  I was trying to write a code that allowed the user (my friend) to change between people's contacts, but I keep getting an error.

For example, I would type `ezramason` (i.e. `ezra mason` but without spaces), and after that it was supposed to let the person return to contacts and select another individual. 
 However, most of the time it just messes up and stops.

Also, can you help me add those cool effects where it adds individual character after one another in a sentence, im a beginner so I couldn't understand how to do it.

```js
des2 = input("Would you like to be redirected to main page or contacts?") 
if des2 == "contacts": 
  print() 
  print ("| Ezra Mason | Nik Malikov | Hanna Donnelly") 
  #contact options 

des3 = input("Who would you like to contact?") 
if des3 == "ezra mason": 
  print ("") 
  print ("") 
  print("") 
  print (" Personel is not active ") 
  print ("") 
  print ("") 
  print ("") 
  print ("| Ezra Mason | Nik Malikov | Hanna Donnelly") 
des3 = input("Who would you like to contact?")  
if des3 == "nik malikov": 
  print ("|Nik Malikov| Date:08/09/75| Location:Heimdall|") 
  print ("") 
  print ("") 
  print ("0:34 ───|────── 0:53") 
  print ("|◁    II       ▷|")  
  print ("") 
  print ("") 
  print ("'I'm bacc lmao", login, "I just sent you the URL for the surveillance footage in your Karezna email. It took me forever to find it so you better thank me later") 
  print ("") 
  print ("") 
  print (" Redirecting to Contacts") 
  print () 
  print() 
  print () 
  print ("| Ezra Mason | Nik Malikov | Hanna Donnelly") 
des3 = input("Who would you like to contact?") 
if des3 == "hanna donnelly": 
  print() 
  print() 
  print() 
  print ("|Hanna Donnelly| Date:08/07/75| Location:Heimdall|") 
  print ("") 
  print ("") 
  print ("1:42 ───|────── 3:57") 
  print ("|◁    II       ▷|") 
  print("") 
  print("") 
  print("") 
  print("", login, "It's not just me, no one trusts nik. Listen he's weird like really weird, but it's your choice if you want to invite him to the party. Your my bestfriend, you understand I'm helping you right? (", login,": I know, don't worry, I'll keep an eye on him in the party. Hannah Donnely: Listen, I love you and all, but dad needs me to help get his telegram out of the toilet, again. Don't forget, I'm picking you up at 8 Pm for the party and bring 70 iSH.")
  print()
  print ()
  print ()
  print ("| Ezra Mason | Nik Malikov | Hanna Donnelly") 
des3 = input("Who would you like to contact?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't ask for the name multiple times. Ask for it just once, then check that input against all the different names.

If you want to do it repeatedly, use a `while` loop.

```
des2 = input("Would you like to be redirected to main page or contacts?") 
if des2 == "contacts": 
    print() 

    while True:
        print ("| Ezra Mason | Nik Malikov | Hanna Donnelly") 
        #contact options 

        des3 = input("Who would you like to contact (or 'done')?")
        if des3 == "ezra mason": 
            print ("") 
            print ("") 
            print("") 
            print (" Personel is not active ") 
            print ("") 
            print ("") 
            print ("") 

        elif des3 == "nik malikov": 
            print ("|Nik Malikov| Date:08/09/75| Location:Heimdall|") 
            print ("") 
            print ("") 
            print ("0:34 ───|────── 0:53") 
            print ("|◁    II       ▷|")  
            print ("") 
            print ("") 
            print ("'I'm bacc lmao", login, "I just sent you the URL for the surveillance footage in your Karezna email. It took me forever to find it so you better thank me later") 
            print ("") 
            print ("") 
            print (" Redirecting to Contacts") 
            print () 
            print() 
            print () 

        elif des3 == "hanna donnelly": 
            print() 
            print() 
            print() 
            print ("|Hanna Donnelly| Date:08/07/75| Location:Heimdall|") 
            print ("") 
            print ("") 
            print ("1:42 ───|────── 3:57") 
            print ("|◁    II       ▷|") 
            print("") 
            print("") 
            print("") 
            print("", login, "It's not just me, no one trusts nik. Listen he's weird like really weird, but it's your choice if you want to invite him to the party. Your my bestfriend, you understand I'm helping you right? (", login,": I know, don't worry, I'll keep an eye on him in the party. Hannah Donnely: Listen, I love you and all, but dad needs me to help get his telegram out of the toilet, again. Don't forget, I'm picking you up at 8 Pm for the party and bring 70 iSH.")
            print()
            print ()
            print ()

        elif des3 == "done":
            break
```